# How can I make 'this' equal to another instance of the same class in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I'm working on a Flutter project in which the architecture forces me to use an instance of a class, say `UserModel`, as a value attached to the `BuildContext`. In this way, I can access that class in every part of the app.

Anyway, there are moments in which I want to update the `UserModel`, and not only by changing the value of some of the fields, but updating all of them. At this moment, I am using an horrible function, let's call that `updateUser(final UserModel newInstance)`. It follows an example.

```
class UserModel {
  String name, surname;

  UserModel({required this.name, required this.surname});

  void updateUser(final UserModel newInstance) {
    name = newInstance.name;
    surname = newInstance.surname;
  }
}
```

The main problem with this solution is that it often happens that I add some fields to the `UserModel` class, but I forgot to add them to `updateUser`. Also, the solution I am using looks horrible.

I know that many of you could say that I should enclose the instance of `UserModel` in a `UserModelProvider` class and just replace the value of the `userModel` field. This would not be compatible with the architecture of the software I am developing, so please don't suggest me that.

Comment: Are you wanting to inspect the `newInstance` parameter for all fields, and assign every `newInstance` field to you current instance? That's the type of thing JavaScript or Python can do, but Dart is statically typed, so would need a lot of code, if it's possible at all.

Comment: Yeah, you got me! That's the goal of what I need.

Comment: Java supports this, but for Dart I think you need the `reflectable` package, and annotate the classes you want to inspect with `@Reflector`. But in a statically typed language, it's not simple (e.g. you can't just do an assign, you need to determine field type and have an assign for each type).

Comment: You could sidestep all static typing and store everything in a `Map` of `Object`s. Just copy the map and you're done. But there are a lot of reasons not to do that.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I got it sorted out. The main point to understand is to use reflection, the ability of a program to examine and modify its own structure, behavior, and metadata at runtime.

To do so, I edit my `updateUser` function to be able to loop through the class variables and set them in the new instance. Here is the result.

```
import 'dart:mirrors';

class UserModel {
  String name, surname;

  UserModel({required this.name, required this.surname});

  void updateUser(final UserModel newInstance) {
    final InstanceMirror thisInstanceMirror = reflect(this);
    final InstanceMirror newInstanceMirror = reflect(newInstance);

    final ClassMirror classMirror = thisInstanceMirror.type;

    for (final DeclarationMirror otherField in classMirror.declarations.values) {
      // We exclude fields that are not variables, like functions
      if (otherField is VariableMirror) {
        // We exclude constant, final and static variables
        if (!otherField.isConst && !otherField.isFinal && !otherField.isStatic) {
          // Finally we update the field with the new value
          thisInstanceMirror.setField(otherField.simpleName,
            newInstanceMirror.getField(otherField.simpleName).reflectee);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return "Name: $name, Surname: $surname";
  }
}
```

So now I can use an instance of the class to update itself, for instance by fetching new values from Firestore.
It follows an example of the functioning.

```
void main() {
  final UserModel user = UserModel(name: "John", surname: "Doe");
  final UserModel user2 = UserModel(name: "Jane", surname: "Doe");

  print(user); // Name: John, Surname: Doe
  print(user2); // Name: Jane, Surname: Doe

  user.updateUser(user2);

  print(user); // Name: Jane, Surname: Doe
}
```

And this is crucial if my `UserModel` is being served by `Provider`, and therefore attached to the `BuildContext`.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, it's hard to understand your issue.

If I'm not wrong, you are looking for `copyWith` method.

```
class UserModel {
  String name, surname;

  UserModel({required this.name, required this.surname});

  UserModal copyWith({
     String? name,
     String? surname,
  }) => UserModel(
          name: name?? this.name,
          surname: surname ?? this.surname);
}
```

With this method, you will be able to update one or both variable.

```
final  foo = UserModel("foo","foo2");

final boo = foo.copyWith(); // boo = UserModel("foo","foo2");

final yoo = foo.copyWith(name:"yoo"); // yoo = UserModel("yoo","foo2");

// update foo
 foo = foo.copyWith(surname:"update foo"); // foo = UserModel("foo","update foo");
```

---

### Updated

I don't know why you force to update it, the concept is the same.

```
class UserModel {
...
 UserModel updateWITHMODELASYOUWANT( UserModel data){
  return UserModel(
    name: data.name, 
    surname: data.surname,
 }
}
```

As I said in the comments, you update the instance, not the object model.

`foo` is an instance of `UserModel`

Comment: Hi, nope: what I need to do is update an entire instance of a class with a method inside that same class. I mean, roughly speaking, assigning "this".

Comment: boo is new instance.  foo = foo.copyWith() is also new updated instance

Comment: if you want update the instance, you need to do is update the `foo`, not the `UserModel`.

Comment: No, the point is that I need to assign an instance of a field to a newer one, inside a method of the same instance. Just look at my code. If I could be able to loop through the fields of UserModel, I would have the solution.

Comment: its same. just change the argument

Comment: The concept is not the same, you are, with your update, returning a NEW instance of UserModel. I need to update all the fields of the current instance - that is btw a ChangeNotifier, and that's why I need the instance to stay the same - without reassigning it.

So, as I already mentioned, I want to do something similar to looping on all the new instance fields and assigning them to the instance that I am in.

Comment: i didnt see any `ChangeNotifier` there.

Comment: `foo` is an instance. i repeat foo is an instance. thats why the method iside the class  is return thats model

Comment: Please see my own answer that explains the solution and lets you understand whaat I was looking for.